# How to use BottomNavigationView with single activity architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I am using the navigation architecture component for my project and planned to use Single Activity architecture. So my app flow is as follows:

`SplashScreen`->`LoginScreen`->`HomeScreen`

`SplashScreen`, `LoginScreen` and `HomeScreen` are Fragments.

I have only one activity which will have a `NavHostFragment`. As per the design, I want to add a `bottomNavigationView` in my `HomeScreen` but since the `HomeScreen` is a fragment where will I host the `bottomNavigationView`?

Answer (score 2):

You could put another `NavHostFragment` into `HomeScreen` and also add the `BottomNavigationView` there.

Your use-case sounds like it's actually containing two distinct navigations:

- The main navigation `SplashScreen`->`LoginScreen`->`HomeScreen`
- The home navigation within the `HomeScreen`

Comment: Can I put `NavHostFragment` inside a `Fragment`?

Comment: Sure. It's just another fragment which would be attached to the `childFragmentManager`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want, in every fragment BottomNavigationView will be available? That means all the fragment can access the BottomNavigationView ?

Comment: `SplashScreen` and `LoginScreen` won't show `BottomNavigationView` but the `HomeScreen` will show.

Comment: Have you tried to set in `BottomNavigationView` in the `HomeScreen` fragment?